# Fetch records with ManyToMany relation in one query

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, associations

I have 2 entities, **Picture** and **Tag**, with ManyToMany relation.  That means 3 tables: *picture*, *tag* and *pictures_tags*.

I want to select some pictures and join their tags in the same query. How can it be done in DQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is fairly simple, and it is all about [fetch-joins](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins):

```
$picture = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT p, t FROM Entity\Picture p JOIN p.tags t WHERE p.id = :pictureId"
)->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $em->createQuery("Select * from pictures p 
join pictures_tags pt on p.pictureid=pt.pictureid 
join tag on tag.id=pt.tagid");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Class 'pictures_tags' is not defined`. This is the JoinTable that exists in the database, but is not an actual class..